# React hook file loading immediately even when the component bundle is not loaded lazily

Tags: reactjs, react-lazy-load

I have a react component:

```
// fileName: LazyComponent.tsx
import {useSomeHook} from '../useSomeHook';
const Component = () => {
const someDate = useSomeHook();
return <div>Hello World</div>
}
```

Here's Lazy component implementation:

```
// Filename: LazyLoader.tsx
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react'
const LazyComponent = lazy(() =>
  import('../LazyComponent/index').then(({ Component }) => ({ default: Component })),
)
function LazyLoader() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <LazyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  )
}

export default LazyLoader
```

Now I have a component which loads the above component lazily:

```
// fileName: Main.tsx
/* eslint-disable import/no-cycle */
import LazyLoader from './LazyLoader'


const ActiveComponent = ({ enable }: { enable?: boolean }) => {
  if (!enable) return null
  return <LazyLoader />
}

export { ActiveComponent }
```

When I inspect my sources of devtools, I dont see `LazyComponent.tsx` which is expected when enable is false. However even though my `LazyComponent.tsx` is not loaded, my useSomeHook.tsx shows up in sources bundle of inspect tab which is getting me confused.

I have made sure that this is used nowhere else but still see it like this. Does anyone know what possibly could cause this?